# Reusing Dedupe training for Gazetteer matching

Tags: python-dedupe

I'm using the Dedupe library to clean up some data. However, once the first deduplication is done using [the Dedupe object](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#dedupe.Dedupe), I understand we are supposed to use [the Gazetteer object](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#gazetteer-objects) to match any new incoming data against the clustered data.

For the sake of explaining the issue, let's assume that :

- The first batch of data is 500k rows of restaurants, with name, address, and phone number fields.
- The second batch of data is, for instance, 1k new restaurants that did not exist at the time, but that I now want to match against the first 500k.

If I describe the pipeline, it goes something like this :

- Step 1) Initial deduplication

  - Train a Dedupe object on a sample of the 500k restaurants
  - Cluster the 500k rows with a Dedupe / Static Dedupe object
- Step 2) Incremental deduplication

  - Train a Gazetteer object on a sample of the 500k restaurants vs 1k new restaurants
  - Match incoming 1k rows against 500k previous rows
  - Assign canonical ID according to the 1k rows that actually matched an existing restaurant

So, the questions are :

- Is the pipeline actually correct ?
- Do I have to retrain the Gazetteer each time new data comes in ?

  - Can't I use the same blocking rules that I learned during the first step ? Or at least the same labelled pairs ? Assuming of course the fields are the same, and the data goes through exactly the same preprocessing.
- I understand I could keep redoing step 1, but from what I read, is not the best practice.

[@fgregg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98080/fgregg) I went through all the Stackoverflow and Github issues [(most recent one being this one)](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues/799), but could not find any helpful answers.

Thanks !

Comment: I am also interested in this use case. Any update?